# not able to get value of labels that I have set in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am setting the value of two labels using javascript. My code works fine when I set the text of the two labels. However, I want to use text of label on a button click, but I am not able to get the value of the label.

My javascript is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function getIndex(index, x,fid) {
    // alert('You have Selected Flight Number:' + index);

    if (x == "a") {
       document.getElementById('lblAmount').innerHTML = index;
       document.getElementById('lblFlight1').innerHTML = fid;
    }
    if (x == "b") {
       document.getElementById('lblAmount1').innerHTML = index;
       document.getElementById('lblFlight2').innerHTML = fid;
    }

    var am1, am2, amount;
    am1 = document.getElementById('lblAmount').innerHTML;
    am2 = document.getElementById('lblAmount1').innerHTML;
    amount = parseFloat(am1) + parseFloat(am2);

    document.getElementById('Amount').innerHTML = amount.toString();
}
</script>
```

My two labels are :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFlight1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblFlight2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label
```

The code where I get the values of the labels:

```
Dim f1 As String = lblFlight1.Text
Dim f2 As String = lblFlight2.Text
Response.Redirect("AirPrice.aspx?Flight1=" & f1 & "&Flight2=" & f2)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to get the value of something set with javascript (on the client) with vb (on the server)? If that's the case, then you can't do that because the server has no idea what javascript does; it compiles your code and then ships it off to the browser with no knowledge of what will change there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody will correct me if I'm wrong, but a label does not maintain viewstate, ie. If you change it on the client side, it's not posted back to the server, the server only knows the original value.

A hidden field however does maintain viewstate, so you could put the text into a hidden field.

Set the value in jQuery

```
$("#hiddenfieldid").val("value in here");
```

Then VB

```
Dim f1 As String = hiddenfield1.value
Dim f2 As String = hiddenfield2.value
Response.Redirect("AirPrice.aspx?Flight1=" & f1 & "&Flight2=" & f2)
```